# Finding shortest path contaning exactly one negative edge in a graph

Tags: graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am given a directed graph with a weight function and a vertex s.
My goal is to find for any other vertex v, the shortest path from s to v that goes through exactly one negative edge. The time complexity of the algorithm should be O(|E| + |V|*log|V|), so guess I need to use Dijkstra's algorithm somehow.

I am guessing that I need to translate my given graph somehow to a new graph with non-negative weights that a shortest path from s to v in this graph will be equivalent to the required shortest path in the given graph.. or maybe I need to modify Dijkstra's algorithm somehow??

I tried to think about it a little, don't have any ideas right now... :(

Comment: I think your problem needs more defining. Do you want to find (A)the shortest path,(B)just a path with only one negative edge on it or (C) the shortest path with exactly one negative edge. Does your graph contain negative cycles? I think I have some solutions but would like some more info before I post the correct one

Comment: My best guess is there's a mistake in your problem statement and that it should actually be "Finding shortest path in a graph containing exactly one negative edge". Such problem is given [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~randall/Algs06/hw3.pdf) and the solution [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~randall/Algs06/HW3_solns.pdf)